# How to enable role selection within a template field

Tags: templates

Is there a way to define a template field where a user can select a Sitecore role from a dropdown? I noticed that in Sitecore 8.2 under the **Developer Types** section there is a `Sitecore User` field type, its a pity they didn't make a `Sitecore Role` one as well while they were at it... My next choice would be to just use a single-line text field which I can just about justify since this is for an admin feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

If you mean, is there an OOTB solution for this, the answer is unfortunately no.

### Alternatives

The question has come up before. I'm sure you found this as well. The solutions listed here are pretty dated and I'm hoping someone has a more current recommendation. However this might give you some ideas.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570890/sitecore-droplink-for-user-roles

All solutions listed here involve some form of creating your own FieldType and adding it to Sitecore.

### My suggestion

If you're going down the route of a custom field, my suggestion would be to base your code on the UnboundDropList custom field. I use this or variations of this on most projects I get involved in. Full reference source here:

- https://github.com/getfishtank/Sitecore-UnboundDroplist/blob/master/src/Fishtank.SharedSource.CustomFields/Fields/UnboundDroplist.cs

To achieve what you want, you would alter line 36:

```
foreach (string s in Source.Split('|'))
```

To something like this:

```
foreach(Role r in RoleManager.GetAllRoles())
```

And remove this condition:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Source))
{
    error = "No source list specified for field";
}
```

And that should be pretty much all you need. I didn't have time to compile, set up and test unfortunately.